# Is this all solutions to $f(x)+(x-i)f'(x)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have encountered the differential equation
$$f(x)+(x-i)f'(x)=0$$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, that we can also rewrite
$$\frac{d\log f(x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{i-x}\quad .$$

$f(x)=\frac{c}{i-x}$ is a solution (for any constant $c$), but I can also find $f(x)=c\frac{e^{-i\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Is there other solutions?

I have found these solutions by two different methods (direct integration and Fourier transform). Is there a method that yields all solutions?

**EDIT**

**I am very sorry for this sign error, the differential equation I am considering is now correct...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After edit:**

Your first solution is indeed the general solution for the equation, there are no other solutions (though there could be equivalent forms). Your second solution also works (c=i). Since you've found a general solution with 1 degree of freedom (the constant $c$) for a first order ODE, this means that there are no other solutions.

---

**Original answer** for the ODE $f(x)=(x-i)f'(x)$.

Whats wrong with your solutions:

Your first solution is wrong. The first one gives $$f(x)=\frac c{i-x}\implies f'(x)=\frac c{(i-x)^2}\implies(x-i)f'(x)=\frac c{x-i}=-f(x)\ne f(x)$$The second one simplifies using $e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ to give $$f(x)=c\frac{e^{-i\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{1-ix}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+ix}=\frac{-i}{x-i}$$ which also incorrect.

Rather than guessing these particular solutions, it is better to solve the differential equation properly to ensure you have all the solutions possible.

---

How to get all the solutions:

$$f(x)=(x-i)f'(x)\\\frac1{x-i}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)\\\implies \log f(x)=\int\frac1{x-i}\,dx=\log(x-i)+A\\\implies f(x)=C(x-i)$$This is the general solution.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the simplification. This second solution was looking strange. So no mystery...!

Comment: @Alexandre Yep, it did look odd. I edited the answer based on the edit in the question by the way.

Comment: OK thank you for the precisions. However the "second" solution (the alternate form) seems correct to me, with $c=i$.

Comment: @Alexandre yeah i had the fraction the wrong way up

Answer (score 0):

You can plug in your solution into the differential equation, your solution is not right! It is $$y(x)=C(x-i)$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be written

$$((x-i)f(x))'=0$$

or

$$(x-i)f(x)=C.$$

There is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to $$(x-i)f^\prime(x) - f(x) =0.$$

Writing $$(x-i) y^\prime - y = 0$$ and multiplying by an integrating factor $\displaystyle \mu=e^{-\int \frac{dx}{x-i}}$ yields $$\frac{d}{dx} \left( -\frac{y}{x-i}\right)=0$$ so the solution is $$-\frac{y}{x-i}=\textrm{constant}$$ or $$y=c(x-i).$$

The **new** equation $$(x-i)f^\prime(x) + f(x) = 0$$ has integrating factor $\tilde{\mu}=x-i$ with solution  $$y=\frac{c}{x-i}.$$